# DLL not found when using .net dll in monotouch

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to using the star micronics sdk for a bluetooth printer in my ipad application using monotouch - I read somewhere that you may be able to reference .net dlls inside of your mono touch application - so it was my attempt to do that...one dll was added without any issue - however a second dll says that it is not a valid .net assembly...so I run my program without the second dll and it builds and when I make a call to the star micronics code a DLL is not found exception is thrown...is there anyway to go about adding this second dll to my monotouch project...

I'm using the sdk from [here](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx).

Edit: If im not mistaken my application does not need to reference the second dll...however the one I added needs to reference that one - would I still need to add a reference to the second ell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second .dll is not a .NET assembly then it won't work with Xamarin.iOS, i.e. a native library x86 library compiled for Windows won't work on OSX (simulator) or on iOS devices (ARM CPUs).

In this case you should use the iOS SDK (from your link) and create (or find an existing) binding assembly for it to use inside your application.

Comment: I believe that the second .dll is a .net assembly...and looking at the ios sdk there are no .m (implementation files) to go with the headers - is this needed to create static library?

Comment: *a second dll says that it is not a valid .net assembly* makes it sound non .NET - why do you believe it is ? (please edit your question to provide the actual error/warning message). The iOS SDK download  is likely providing the static library (unless it's open source it would not ship the `.m` files) and you only need the header file to create bindings.

Comment: no it actually says that it is not a .net assembly - I just thought that because it was being used in a .net project that it would be but i may be mistaken - going with the ios sdk there is a file called stario no extension - cant open it dont know what it is - should i rename that to stario.a (would that be my static library) otherwise there is nothing but headers - and i couldnt create a library based off of those? Sorry but im extra noob to this

Comment: use `lipo -info stario` and it will tell you if it's an executable and which architectures are available, e.g. you need `i386` for the simulator and `armv7` for devices (but there might be more, like `armv6` for older devices and `armv7s` for the new iPhone5 A6 CPU)

Comment: Ahhh it is Architectures in the fat file: StarIO are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) i386 - so this means that this is the static library?

Comment: So it's the static library. Now you need to do the bindings, see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries for instructions (but google first in case someone else already did the work ;-)

Comment: I checked and it doesnt seem to be done already...I had already used Objective Sharpie to create the bindings for the headers so hopefully this will work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32445/discussion-between-jharr100-and-poupou)

Comment: @jharr100 Did you manage to get the binding to work? I'm trying to use it in a project I'm doing and was wondering (hoping) if you'd uploaded it anywhere :)